# How to submit form with values using jsoup?

Tags: android, forms, jsoup

I am working on an application and i need duplicate a contact form from the website. http://www.telekino.com.ar/info/contacto. I am understand the jsoup principles to get data, but I am not good with the concept to send data.
And the submit button doesnt have a web or mail address to be clear for me where i send the data.

This is my code

```
public class Contactenos extends Fragment {

public Contactenos(){}

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public static String namet;
public static String localidadt;
public static String telefonot;
public static String emailt;
public static String consultat;
public static String maildestt;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;


String url = "http://www.telekino.com.ar/info/contacto/#contactenos";
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacto, container, false);

    EditText name=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    EditText localidad=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.localidad);
    EditText telefono=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.telefono);
    EditText email=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    EditText consulta=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.consulta);

    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.maildest);

    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) rg.findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    maildestt= String.valueOf(rb);


    namet = name.getText().toString();
    localidadt = localidad.getText().toString();
    telefonot = telefono.getText().toString();
    emailt = email.getText().toString();
    consultat=consulta.getText().toString();


    Button sendbut= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    sendbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Title().execute();

        }
    });




    return rootView;
}



// Title AsyncTask
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String sorteofech;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("TELEKINO");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("enviando...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Connect to the server and do a post
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("nombre", namet)
                    .data("localidad", localidadt)
                    .data("telefono", telefonot)
                    .data("email", emailt)
                    .data("dpto", maildestt)
                    .data("consulta", consultat)
                    .post();





        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }


}
```

}

This way crash, and I am not sure if work anyway.

this one is teh Logcat

```
07-15 12:37:35.899    1329-1329/info.blacktrail.telekino E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.blacktrail.telekino, PID: 1329
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
        at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
        at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:58)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.isReadable(HttpConnection.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.isReadable(Connection.java:259)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:110)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:176)
        at info.blacktrail.telekino.Contactenos$Title.onPostExecute(Contactenos.java:107)
        at info.blacktrail.telekino.Contactenos$Title.onPostExecute(Contactenos.java:79)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

How can I fix it or what is the best method to reply this contact form on android?

Comment: Run your code, which makes the post request in `doInBackground()` and not in `onPostExecute()`. Also, declare your `EditText`, `RadioGroup` and `RadioButton` objects as class objects. Currently they are local to `onCreate()`, so you cannot access them outside it's context.

Comment: Ok. And this code is fine? Is necessary add lines?

Comment: I am not familiar with `jsoup` but logically it seems fine. I told you the solution based on your exception and the mistake that I could find. Try running it and see if it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

Call your connect method inside doInBackground. Then it will run the network request in background thread.

OnPostExecute will run on main thread , not in background. To do background task, use doInBackGround.

If you want to update UI from results of http request, then use doInBackGround.

Comment: yes code is fine. just add //connect to the website code in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory. Newer versions of Android don't allow long operations (e.g. network) on the UI thread. You're performing the network operation (jsoup) on `onPostExecute(Void result)` which runs on the main thread.

You should move the code in `doInBackground()` instead:

```
// Title AsyncTask
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("TELEKINO");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("enviando...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Connect to the server and do a post
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .data("nombre", namet)
                    .data("localidad", localidadt)
                    .data("telefono", telefonot)
                    .data("email", emailt)
                    .data("dpto", maildestt)
                    .data("consulta", consultat)
                    .post();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Note: I've just moved around your code (and cleaned up the unused variable), so there might be some syntax errors.